# Show that $(1-\varepsilon(n, d)) \sqrt{d}$ is a lower bound of $\lambda=\max _{i \neq 1}\left|\lambda_i\right|$

Tags: geometry, inequality, graph-theory, adjacency-matrix

**Problem:** Let $G$ be a $d$-regular graph with adjacency matrix $A$ and eigenvalues $\lambda_1 \geq$ $\lambda_2 \geq \cdots \geq \lambda_n$. Let $\lambda=\max _{i \neq 1}\left|\lambda_i\right|$ be the largest absolute value of an eigenvalue other than $\lambda_1$.

1. Find a lower bound (in terms of the degree) on the diagonal entries of $A^2$.
2. Show that
   $$
   \lambda \geq(1-\varepsilon(n, d)) \sqrt{d}
   $$
   where $\varepsilon(n, d)$ tends to zero as $n \rightarrow +\infty$. You may use the fact that $\lambda_1 =d$.

**My attempt:**

1. For any $i \in \left\{1,\ldots,n\right\}$, we have
   \begin{align*}
   (A^2)_{ii} &= \sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij}a_{ji} = \sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij}^2 \\
   & \ge \dfrac{1}{n}(\sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij})^2 \tag{C-S inequality}\\
   & = \dfrac{d^2}{n} \tag{G is $d$-regular}
   \end{align*}
2. Firstly, we diagonalize $A$ as
   $$A = P^{-1}TP,$$
   where $T = \text{diag}(\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_n)$ are diagonal eigenvalues matrix.

Hence,
$$\text{Tr}(A^2) = \text{Tr}(P^{-1}T^2P) = \text{Tr}(PP^{-1}T^2) = \sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i^2.$$

By the fact $\lambda_1 = d$ and the definition of $\lambda$, we obtain that
\begin{align*}
\text{Tr}(A^2) = d^2 + \sum_{i=2}^n \lambda_i^2 \le d^2 + (n-1)\lambda^2. \tag{1}
\end{align*}
By using the question 1, we have
\begin{align*}
\text{Tr}(A^2) = \sum_{i=1}^n (A^2)_{ii} \ge \sum_{i=1}^n \dfrac{d^2}{n} = d^2 \tag{2}.
\end{align*}
Now, I was stuck here. I wonder anyone could give me some hints to deal with the second question.

Comment: @ThànhNguyễn Sorry, it is my typo =))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The diagonal term $(A^2)_{ii}$ is at least $d$:
$$
      (A^2)_{ii} = \sum_{j = 1}^n a_{ij}^2 \ge \sum_{j = 1}^n a_{ij} = d \hspace{0.25cm} (a_{ij}^2 \ge a_{ij} \ \forall i,j)
$$
Thus, by combining the upper bound in your post, we get the following
$$
    nd \le \text{tr}(A^2) \le d^2 + (n - 1)\lambda^2
$$
or equivalently,
$$
     \lambda^2 \ge \dfrac{d(n - d)}{n - 1} \ge 0
$$
Therefore,
$$
     \lambda \ge (1 - \epsilon(n, d))\sqrt{d}
$$
where
$$
    \epsilon(n, d) = 1 - \sqrt{\dfrac{n - d}{n - 1}} \xrightarrow{n \rightarrow \infty} 0
$$

Comment: Your answer is perfectly true if the graph $G$ is simple (no loops and no multiple edges). In the case $G$ is not simple, $a_{ij}$ might not be in $\left\{0,1\right\}$.

Comment: @TungNguyen Updated. The inequality $a_{ij}^2 \ge a_{ij}$ will do fine

Comment: Just a funny question: Are you Thành at HCMUS (if yes, I know you =)) ).